# Re titling a article/document based on the content in R/Python

Tags: python, r, node.js, nlp, weka

I am trying to title an article based on the content and unable to get it right. I am using LDA package in R

Basically it fits a generative topic model which accounts for both the words which occur in a collection of documents as well as the links between the documents.

```
rtm.collapsed.gibbs.sampler(documents, links, K, vocab, num.iterations,
alpha, eta, beta, trace = 0L, test.start = length(documents) + 1L)
rtm.em(documents, links, K, vocab, num.e.iterations, num.m.iterations,
alpha, eta, lambda = sum(sapply(links, length))/(length(links) *(length(links) -1)/2), initial.beta = rep(3, K), trace = 0L,
test.start = length(documents) + 1L, tempering = 0.0)
```

This isn't working great! Can Somebody help me on this please ?

Comment: How do you know it isn't working?

Comment: @Peter, applied it on a sample list of articles and it is not doing a great job!

Comment: How would you define *'a great job*'?

Comment: @Peter, LDA is good when we have to use it for a topic modeling/document classification. In my case, I am trying to title an article/document based on the content and exploring ways to achieve it.                                                          Ex: There is an article which could be titled as "A SQUIRT OF STEM CELL GEL HEALS BRAIN INJURIES" post reading the content

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [textteaser](https://github.com/DataTeaser/textteaser), described in the following [medium article](https://medium.com/@mojojolo/automatic-summarization-in-medium-59b1747c1d36#.vws8yw55r).

Comment: Thanks Victor, Let me explore and post it back if I find it useful.